# How to configure a read-only server with MariaDB Maxscale

Tags: mariadb, maxscale

Is it possible to configure a read-only server that remains slave even though no more masters are available with MariaDB Maxscale 6.
I tried it with a readconroute router, but that one turned the slave eventually in to a master as well.

/Theo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the `mariadbmon` monitor, you can use the [`servers_no_promotion`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-maxscale-6-mariadb-monitor/#servers_no_promotion) parameter to list the server you want to remain read-only.

For `galeramon` there should be no need to keep servers as read-only as all functioning nodes are capable of receiving writes.